# Not working git stash

Tags: intellij-idea, git-stash

I use `VNC -> Git -> Stash Changes` in Intellj IDEA

I get error:
[image]

I run

```
  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

But it still not working. Why?

Comment: Can you try running `git stash` from the command line?  Your calls to `git config` should have fixed this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my mistake. 
I set `user.mail` instead `user.email`.